# How to create partitioning dynamically in SSAS tabular model, without using the SSIS package?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssas

I would like to create the dynamic partition in one of my SSAS tabular model.
To do so I found one approach with SSIS package which involves the "Analysis Services Processing Task" & the script task integration, thing is I would like implement this solution without introducing any SSIS package in between, may be via SQL itself (?).
Would it be possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, by using XMLA ([for example](https://kevinmintmier.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/processing-ssas-objects-with-t-sql-part-1-of-2/)). There are slight differences between tabular and multidimensional, but both modes support XMLA. Processing and generating SSAS metadata and XMLA dynamically quickly gets uncomfortable in SQL, though, because T-SQL is just not a very good programming language on its own.

Comment: There are many API's into SSAS. SQL isn't one of them unfortunately. What are your reasons for not using SSIS (So we may suggest another method which doesn't have the same constraints). For example you could use Powershell. You could use ASCMD.EXE https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2654/using-ascmd-to-run-command-line-scripts-for-sql-server-analysis-services/

Comment: Thanks  Jeroen Mostert  for your suggestion.

Comment: Hi Nick, there is not such restriction of not using the SSIS package but currently our cube processing handled with one SQL job. This job itself has other steps to perform various other tasks. So we though not to introduce SSIS execution in between. But i think I should go with SSIS which seems to be perfect option here.Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. if you don't want to use SSIS, you can create a job and run your XMLA codes in steps (via SQL Server Analysis services command code step type )
or
you can create a linked server between the SQL server database engine and SQL server analysis service tabular and run your XMLA codes

EXEC (xmla_query) AT [Link server name]